# Phing deploy fails with database migration

Tags: svn, deployment, zend-framework2, phing

I am trying to use **Phing** to deploy my project. The `Checkout from SVN` and `Running Composer` scripts work great but the migration for my database doesn't. Here's the error message:

> Execution of target "migration" failed for the following reason: Task exited with code 2
>   sh: cannot open build/scripts/deploy-.sql: No such file

It seems that the delta file is not generated by Phing.

My `Migration` script looks like this:

```xml
<target name="migration" description="Datenbankmigration">
  <property file="${phing.dir}/includes/build.properties"/>
  <propertyprompt propertyName="db.name" defaultValue="${db.name}" promptText="Datenbankname angeben falls nicht der Defaultwert genutzt werden soll. Default:" />
  <propertyprompt propertyName="db.username" defaultValue="${db.username}" promptText="Datenbankbenutzernamen angeben falls nicht der Defaultwert genutzt werden soll. Default:" />
  <propertyprompt propertyName="db.password" defaultValue="" promptText="Datenbankpasswort angeben falls nicht der Defaultwert genutzt werden soll. Default:" />
  <propertyprompt propertyName="db.host" defaultValue="${db.host}" promptText="Host angeben falls nicht der Defaultwert genutzt werden soll. Default:" />

  <!-- load the dbdeploy task -->
  <taskdef name="dbdeploy" classname="phing.tasks.ext.dbdeploy.DbDeployTask" />

  <!-- these two filenames will contain the generated SQL to do the deploy and roll it back -->
  <property name="build.dbdeploy.deployfile" value="${phing.dir}build/scripts/deploy-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.sql" />
  <property name="build.dbdeploy.undofile" value="${build.dir}build/scripts/undo-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.sql" />

  <!-- create the changelog Table -->
  <pdosqlexec url="mysql:host=${db.host};dbname=${db.name}" userid="${db.username}" password="${db.password}">
    <transaction src="build/sql/changelog.sql"/>
  </pdosqlexec>

  <!-- generate the deployment scripts -->
  <dbdeploy
    url="mysql:host=${db.host};dbname=${db.name}"
    userid="${db.username}"
    password="${db.password}"
    dir="${phing.dir}/sql/delta"
    outputfile="${build.dbdeploy.deployfile}"
    undooutputfile="${build.dbdeploy.undofile}" />

  <!-- execute the SQL - Use mysql command line to avoid trouble with large
  files or many statements and PDO -->
  <exec
    command="mysql -h${db.host} -u${db.username} -p${db.password} ${db.name} &lt; ${build.dbdeploy.deployfile}"
    dir="${phing.dir}"
    checkreturn="true"
    output="${phing.dir}/cache/deploy-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.log"
    error="${phing.dir}/cache/deploy-error-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.log"
  />

  <echo msg="Datenbank erfolgreich angelegt"/>

</target>
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems like you forgot the `<tstamp />` tag in your target so that the `${DSTAMP}` and `${TSTAMP}` variables work.

Then you should define your properties like this :

```
<property name="build.dbdeploy.deployfile" value="deploy-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.sql" />
<property name="build.dbdeploy.undofile" value="undo-${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}.sql" />
```

They should be automatically placed in the directory you specified in the `dir` argument.